# Problem on composition two linear maps on a vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ P$ be the vector space of all polynomials over $\mathbb R$. Let T and S be two linear maps from  $ P$ to itself such that $T\circ S$ is the identity map.

Then which of the following are correct?

1. $S\circ T$ may not be the identity map.
2. $S\circ T$ must be identity map, but S and T need not be the identity map.
3. S and T must be the identity maps.
4. There exists a scalar $\alpha$ such that $ T(\alpha)=\alpha p$ for all $p \in P $

I have no idea how to solve this type of problem. Please help.  Since TOS=I,then can we say T ans S are invertible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: what if $T$ is differentiation? Can you find an appropriate $S$?

Comment: In this case is ToS=I ?

Comment: What is $S$? You haven't said.

Comment: Given condition is ToS=I, for the differentiation map we have to find S .What is S ?I am confused,Can u explain it.

Comment: If $f$ is any polynomial, and $\frac{d}{dx}(S(f)) = f$, what does $S$ have to do to $f$?

Comment: is S  integral map?

Comment: Yes. But which one? (there are many integrals of $2x$, for example: $x^2$, $x^2+0.5$, $x^2+17$, and so forth).